# PriorityDispatcher mentioned in PriorityGenerator API documentation seems to be missing (Akka 2.0RC2)

Tags: scala, akka

I was using the `PriorityExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher` class in Akka 1.3.

In Akka 1.3 documentation, the `PriorityGenerator` API documentation at http://akka.io/api/akka/1.3/#akka.dispatch.PriorityGenerator says:

> A PriorityGenerator is a convenience API to create a Comparator that
>   orders the messages of a PriorityExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher

The PriorityGenerator API documentation for Akka 2.0 RC2 at http://akka.io/api/akka/2.0-RC2/#akka.dispatch.PriorityGenerator says:

> A PriorityGenerator is a convenience API to create a Comparator that
>   orders the messages of a PriorityDispatcher

From this, I am guessing that the class `PriorityExecutorBasedEventDrivenDispatcher` in Akka 1.3 is intended to be replaced with the class `PriorityDispatcher` in Akka 2.0 RC2. However, there is no class called `PriorityDispatcher` in Akka 2.0 RC2. The only dispatcher classes available are `Dispatcher`, `BalancingDispatcher`, and `PinnedDispatcher`, none of which seem to respect priorities.

The only type in akka.dispatch that starts with "Priority" is "`PriorityGenerator`" (whose documentation refers to the missing class "`PriorityDispatcher`").

I was wondering if PriorityDispatcher was intended to be there, or if it is expected to become available in future versions of Akka 2.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"PriorityDispatcher" is a remnant from the past. Instructions are here: http://akka.io/docs/akka/2.0-RC2/scala/dispatchers.html#priority-event-based

I'll create a ticket to revise those docs before 2.0 goes final.